# jQuery hide show elements in other div

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I was trying to do a little accordion onepager.
I'm using Wordpress, I hope the outer code is not important.
The code

```
<?php print_menu_item(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() )); ?>
```

produces something like "about menu-item" (depends on the page)
So when clicked on the div with class .about .menu-item I want the_content() of the next div be shown.

I tried this, but it is not working (nothing is happening) - I'm a bloody beginner, so I hope you can help me how to toggle(? is this the right verb?) the next div and show the ".menu-content" inside it.

The problem is, this is a loop & a one pager. This means, there are more  beneath each other. If I normally do hide and show, every item on the page goes hidden or shown. So i really need to adress the div in the section which is clicked.

```
      $(".menu-content").hide();

    $(".menu-item").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("div.menu-content").show();





    <section class="<?php print_post_name(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() )); ?>" id="<?php print_post_name(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() )); ?>">
    <div class="<?php print_menu_item(get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() )); ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="menu-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elementToHide").prop('hidden', 'hidden') //hides
$("#elementToShow").prop('hidden', false) //shows
```

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my post, cause I forgot to mention, that there are more <sections> like that beneath each other. So doing what you recommended, sets every menu-content to show (.about .contact .home). But I only want to show the menu-content in the section ".about" where i clicked on ".menu-item"

Comment: so what you want to do in that case is give them unique id's.

Comment: in the DOM we have classes and id's id's are unique but classes are multi-used; if you want to target a specific element and it isn't for example the element you clicked on you want to have an id to specifically target that. you could also give them unique classes but that would defeat the purpose

Comment: Yes, but that's not the problem as far as I can see. The sections have ids. So I want, that the .menu-item which is clicked, should see in which section it is - if it is in section ".about", the ".menu-content" of ".about" should be shown. I just tried another code, but also does not work

Comment: $(".menu-content").hide();

        $(".menu-item").click(function(e) {
            var sec = $(this).parent("section").attr("id").val();
            $(sec).find(".menu-content").show();
          });

Answer (score 0):

You should try to print elements in console log, you´re actually selecting. For this nested element i would use next().find().

```js
$(".menu-item").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().find(".menu-content").css("display","block" );
});
```

```css
.two .menu-content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="menu">
    <div class="menu-item one">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Click on me
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item two">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="menu-content">
                    and i will show up
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2x1r03b9/1/